# How to set the sender's port in NWConnection for UDP broadcast

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, networking, udp

I have a small ruby server and i would like to send it an UDP message with an iOS application.
It works well but the (sender) iOS port is each time a random port and i would like it to be a fixed one.

Here is the iOS code to send the message :

```
guard let data = "Hello".data(using: .utf8) else { return }
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "connection")
let params = NWParameters.udp
client = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host("255.255.255.255"), port: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: 49000), using: params)
client?.start(queue: queue)
client?.send(content: data, completion: .idempotent)
```

And here is the output of the Ruby server which shows the sender and the message :

```
AF_INET
51269 <----------- Port is not 49001
192.168.1.241
192.168.1.241
48656c6c6f
AF_INET
60451 <----------- Port is not 49001
192.168.1.241
192.168.1.241
48656c6c6f
```

I tried to add this parameter to set the sender socket with a fixed value of 49001.

```
params.requiredLocalEndpoint = NWEndpoint.hostPort(host: NWEndpoint.Host("0.0.0.0"), port: 49001)
```

But it don't work neither. Any idea ?

Thank you for your help, the documentation of the Network framework is very poor.

Comment: And the IP address in LocalEndpoint is valid address of actual interface what is used for your connection?

Comment: Hi Lukas, with your comment i checked it on actual iPhone and it works. On a real iOS device the requiredLocalEndpoint parameter do his job. I was testing this only on simulator. Thanks !

Comment: Please do not use broadcast, which is very outdated. Today, we have multicast, and IPv6 does not even have broadcast. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host on the LAN, even things like routers, printers, etc. that have no interest in your broadcast, andall the hosts must process the broadcast to see if it is interested. Multicast only interrupts those hosts listening for the multicast.

Comment: This seems to only work on wifi connection, not mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well with an actual iOS device not on simulator.

Comment: This no longer works reliably for me on real devices anymore, either. There are some conversations in Apple Dev Forums about this, but it does not seem like it will be fixed anytime soon.